# Spring Coud Sleuth causing ActiveMQ/JMS message headers to be lost

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

Versions:

- SpringBoot: 2.3.12.RELEASE
- SpringCloud: Hoxton.SR12
- SpringCloud Starter Sleuth: 3.0.3
- Camel: 3.4.6

I want to add Sleuth to a pre-exisitng project that now makes use of ActiveMQ, previosuly it was jusing JMS. When I do, values from the ActiceMQ message get blocked/removed and (one being "filename" which is the key value for S2 requests). Other JMS values still seem to come through OK.

I need to understand why the non-JMS values are getting blocked/removed (I cannot find any information on what would be causing that to happen) to prevent the errors.

I know I can disbale Sleuth for JMS with `spring.sleuth.messaging.jms.enabled=true` but moving forwards I'd like to be able to trace the ActiveMQ/JMS code, so that workaround isn't particularly attractive.

As this is pre-exiting code, I'd also like to avoid having to re-write it if at all possible.

Has anyone gotten SPring Cloud Sleuth to work with ActiveMQ/JMS and can maybe point out where things are going wrong?

**Edit:**

Based on the initial response from Marcin, we found that the following version compile & execute, although significant problems do remain:

- SpringBoot: 2.4.8
- SpringCloud: 2020.0.3
- Camel: 3.7.5

**Without Sleuth**

ActiveMQ message details:
[image: Without Sleuth]

Log message ("filename", "CamelAwsS3Etag" etc present):

```
2021-08-16 10:10:37.889  INFO [MyApp,,] 28775 --- [umer[taskQueue]] taskQueueConsumer: ***HEADERS IN***: {CamelAwsS3ETag=39d029a87fa4c6aaee5f1de643d9f3f6, Content-Type=application/json, filename=_bl001/group0/_bl001-group0-1629104686042.zip, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSCorrelationIDAsBytes=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=queue://taskQueue, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:server-44053-1629104652998-1:3:1:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1629104686350, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=_bl001-group0, JMSXGroupSeq=0, JMSXUserID=null}
```

**With Sleuth**

ActiveMQ message details:
[image: With Sleuth, "b3" value showing]

Log message ("filename", "CamelAwsS3Etag" etc are missing):

```
2021-08-16 10:24:33.821  INFO [MyApp,,] 31553 --- [umer[taskQueue]] taskQueueConsumer: ***HEADERS IN***: {JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSCorrelationIDAsBytes=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=queue://taskQueue, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:server-42561-1629105658959-1:3:1:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1629105675306, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=_bl000-group1, JMSXGroupSeq=0, JMSXUserID=null}
```

**Sample Java code**

```
@Component
public class MyAppCoreRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    /* Other code */

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("activemq:queue:taskQueue?concurrentConsumers=" + taskNumberOfConcurrentConsumers)
                .log("***HEADERS IN***: ${headers}")
                .routeId("taskQueueConsumer")
                .threads(taskNumberOfConcurrentConsumers)
                .pollEnrich().simple("aws-s3://myapp-task?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&fileName=${header.filename}&operation=getObject")
                .choice()
                .when(header(S3Constants.KEY).endsWith(".zip"))
                .to("file://" + taskLocalUnCompressedEndpoint + "?fileName=${header.CamelAwsS3ETag}/${header.CamelAwsS3Key}")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String camelAwsS3ETag = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelAwsS3ETag", String.class);
                    String camelAwsS3Key = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelAwsS3Key", String.class);
                    File uniqueDir = new File(taskLocalUnCompressedEndpoint, camelAwsS3ETag);
                    File taskZip = new File(uniqueDir, camelAwsS3Key);
                    new ZipFile(taskZip).extractAll(uniqueDir.getAbsolutePath());
                })
                .setHeader("resourceDirectory", simple(taskLocalUnCompressedEndpoint + "/${header.CamelAwsS3ETag}")).setHeader("schedule.time", simple("${date:now}"))
                .removeHeader("CamelAwsS3Headers")
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Processing batch job ${headers}")
                .to("spring-batch:importMyAppRecordJob")
                .endChoice()
                .otherwise()
                .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "Unexpected file type, filtering file name ${header.CamelAwsS3Key} ")
                .end();

        /* Other code */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong versions of Boot, Cloud and Sleuth. To use Sleuth 3.0.x you need to use Cloud 2020.0.x and Boot 2.4.x or 2.5.x.

Comment: According to the docs, Hoxton is correct for Spring Cloud:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/Hoxton.SR12/reference/html/

If that is not correct, what are the correct versions to use with Sping 2.3.12.RELEASE and where is a canonical place to look this up?

Thanks!

Comment: If you go to https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud and read Table 1 you will see that for Hoxton you have to use Boot 2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5). Sleuth version is imposed by the train - you can't arbitrary set its version. So Sleuth for Hoxton is 2.x. Also Hoxton is not maintained anymore so please upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Aahhhh! I appear to have had a minor misunderstanding there (and I see the Sleuth verson mentioned further down that link). Unfortunately the same problem persists with Sleuth 2.2.8.RELEASE.

I cannot upgrade this project, moving to 2.4 or 2.5 breaks it in many ways; probably due to other dependencies. But thank you for the quick repsonses.

Comment: Have just attemed the upgrade and whilst it compiles, there is a runtime failure of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup" which appears to be https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24880

I'll have to go back to the original code authors and get their help with any upgrade. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess we can as the header issue is now solved after finding a set of compatible version. Although the body of the messages is now getting erased by Sleuth, but I will ask a separate question about that.